# How to retrieve SharePoint user data using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, user-data

I am trying to retrieve data from list using LINQ, and have SPMETAl ran for the latest list version. All data from the list is successfully retrieved besides created by, created, modified by, modified. The SPMETAl returned a CS file named marketing and below is the code for my LINQ data retrieval in C#

```
MarketingDataContext newMarket = new MarketingDataContext("http://strikychoong-    lt/marketing");

EntityList<QuotationItem> Quotation = newMarket.GetList<QuotationItem>("Quotation");

searchResult = from searching in Quotation
                           where searching.Title.Equals(TextBox1.Text)
                           select searching;
```

The auto-complete for searching. did show every attributes in the lists besides the 4 user data above.

How can I actually retrieve these 4 data (created by, created, modified by, modified)?

I am very new to SharePoint and LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

these objects (created by, created etc) cannot be targeted by using Linq. If you want to use them, use them the 'oldfashion' way:

```
SPList list = ...

var results =   from item in list.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
        where item["CreatedBy"].ToString().Equals("username")
        select item
```

[msdn info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538669.aspx)

Comment: This is server-side code. The question is asking how to query this from the client. It's also *extremely* slow, as it uses LINQ to Objects, iterates over all list items, casting the author value to a string and comparing it. This may be acceptable in small lists or low traffic sites, but it's murder for production sites. The equivalent CAML query though would be very small and very fast